# Receive an error to install grass-core and liblas3 that requires libgdal1i to be installed

Tags: 16.04, dependencies

I have been having issues with the following packages not being able to be installed/updated. I've tried searching for different solution and using the different terminal commands to update and fix the issue to no avail. How can I fix this issue?

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
     grass-core : Depends: libgdal1i (>= 1.11.0) but it is not installed
                  Recommends: gdal-bin but it is not installed
     liblas3 : Depends: libgdal.so.1-1.11.3
               Depends: libgdal1i (>= 1.10.1) but it is not installed
```

Comment: What are those commands you had already used?

Comment: Try to run `sudo apt -f install`